# How to trigger onkeydown event on HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, key-events

I want to trigger the onkeydown event on the html page to do some actions. I have the following code:

```
document.onkeydown = function(){
    alert('dd');
};
```

Is it possible to trigger this event on whole page or is it limited to only editable html elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger a keypress/keydown/keyup event in JS/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery)

Comment: @Suraj if you use jquery then you can easily do it....

Comment: @Suraj: not everyone uses, can use or wants to use jQuery

Comment: To initiate a event using pure JavaScript, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/7914742/938089

Answer (score 1):

You can just call

```
document.onkeydown();
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the event was added by setting `document.onkeydown = ` directly. If you used addEventListener things are different

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger event on body tag

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

        function changeVal() {
          alert('d');
        } 

        </script>
        </head>

        <body onKeyDown="changeVal();">
        <form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">

        </form>
        </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onkeydown

On an element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onkeydown

Determine which key was pressed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.which