# How to trigger the HTML Select onClick event (activates select dropdown with options)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to know how to trigger the `onClick` event of any `select`(html combobox element).

I tried to do `$('#MySelect').click();` using `jQuery` and tried `document.getElementById('MySelect').click();` using pure javascript.

But the two don't fire the dropdown event that have the options of the select.

Ps: i have sure that selector `$('#MySelect')` exists.

Comment: `$( "#MySelect" ).trigger( "click" );` I think this is what you're looking for

Comment: Do you have a defined `onclick` event? Or an `onchange` event?

Comment: Using pure javascript this is how you would do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914684/trigger-right-click-using-pure-javascript

Comment: @ElliotM i tried this just now, with multiple selects, created another page with another new select too, did a lot of tests using this way and i't dont works.

Comment: @tymeJV no. i did not.

Comment: Do you just need the event you've bound to the click event to fire or do you actually want the select box to open as it would if clicked.  If the latter you may need to create the dropdown menu using something like this: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#dropdowns

Comment: @olleicua Are you Serious??? Ohh no, do you really have sure that is impossible to trigger the html native onclick event of the select?

Comment: This guy did it. It is not a trivial problem. http://code.google.com/p/expandselect/

Comment: I'm not entirely certain that it is impossible I just don't know how.  I suggested using JS to make your own dropdown menu because it's the first thing I would likely try.

Comment: I have stumbled upon this page as I wanted to style a dropdown arrow on a select, where a click would trigger the default behaviour. I can confirm, javascript did not work, but styling the `select:after` with absolute position, etc. it does work but ONLY if you set `pointer-events: none` in CSS. So if somebody is here for the same reason, give it a go. (This won't work in IE < 11 according to the CanIUse site.)

Answer (score 6):

are you looking   for this

```
  document.getElementById("MySelect").selectedIndex=3;
```

Comment: `$('#MySelect').click();` does the same thing

Comment: First solution don't works. Second solution (dispatchEvent) gives me a error: `TypeError: Argument 1 of EventTarget.dispatchEvent is not an object.`

Comment: it is same thing, you only defined that it will run when document is ready. and i want to run in a certain event that i have here.

Comment: check if this is what u want

Comment: @VickyGonsalves what are you doing? i can't understand you... you are posting edits that dont click anything, just change and fires changes events and such. I want `Click` event man. not `Change` event.

Comment: post your question properly or better think what you want before posting it here..we all are not mad here..

Comment: im not mad. i dont know why people think that im mad when i type. i have specified the `onClick` event highlighted properly, you have to pay more attention. i do not want to bring this into a discussion, so, please, dont continue.

Answer (score 1):

Programatically triggering a `click` event will only run the defined click handler for that element. As you say in the comments, you have no such method defined, therefore no action will take place.

Comment: And if it is a native html handler? How i can trigger it?

Comment: What is a native html handler?

Comment: The event that fires: "When you click a fresh html select element with the mouse", That does: "It open a dropdown that contains the options of the select, and a small blank space if it dont have options."

Comment: Not possible. Sorry. You can only give focus.

Comment: Can you show me a documentation that says that it is impossible? Because it is just a click... no way to be a dangerous thing to let javascript do, or something like that to dont allow people to trigger it.

Comment: Here's the answer which discusses it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due -- Many have tried, it doesn't work

Comment: see @chiliNUT's answer. it is possible.

Comment: @PauloRoberto -- Not out of the box without hacking it, if you expand that plugin, as well as read the description: Browsers do not allow expanding <select> in pure javascript, that control can be expanded only by directly clicking on it using the mouse. The "select.click()" won't work. But there is a solution. We imitate expanded <select> control by creating another select with multiple options being displayed at once, this can be done by setting the "size" parameter.

Comment: well, it is a solution, ok to it dont does on "the better way" but it is acceptable because it resolved my problem that was showing the options.

Comment: @PauloRoberto -- Awesome if it solves it, just thought I'd mention it's pretty hacky.

Comment: @PauloRoberto -- I'm also curious, what is the need for this?

Comment: It was needed to a custom grid that i created with html+javascript, that have a edit and when you `keyup` some word on it, it search if this text are contained on options and hide if `false` and show if `true` but i want to after the user typed something the user see the options that he got filtered with the word.

Comment: another use of this is to dynamically create and activate a Select element in a mobile browser, which will cause an OS specific pop-up to appear.