# Onclick on select element not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, select, onclick

I have the following strange behaviour:

```
<select name="blah" id="blah" size="1" onclick="console.log('clicked');">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test</option>
</select>
```

Doesn´t fire when clicked the first time (when opening). It fires when I click a second time and the select element closes. Why?

Edit: added example options to select.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/e5x63, I have three different behaviours on three different browsers (Chrome, Safari and Firefox) with this and also on different OS!

Comment: it fires at the first time, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P38ZQ/)

Comment: it is working, i don't see any problem in your code. Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/JEAZP/

Comment: possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913171/how-to-trigger-the-html-select-onclick-event-activates-select-dropdown-with-opt you find the answer there

Comment: you can use onBlur() method

Comment: @chris Are you using an older browser or mobile device?

Comment: Could be the case that you preventDefault() the select already with some other code. Any conflicts with other code?

Comment: Your code is working check here http://jsfiddle.net/weMTf/

Comment: No I use Chrome and Firefox in latest version, I tryed a workaround with onfocus but I need the click event also when already focused.

Comment: Noone any idea? JsFiddle is not working guys, you need to insert the option elements.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/e5x63/, I have three different behaviours on three different browsers (Chrome, Safari and Firefox) with this.

Comment: Behaviour is also different on different OS!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind event on changing any value from drop down.

```
<select name="bla" id="blubb" size="1" onclick="console.log('test')" onchange="console.log('value Changed')">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
</select>
```