# How to automatically push button after mouse is (automatically) hovering on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, combobox

I am building a bigger application in `React`, `JavaScript` and `HTML`using `Visual Studio Code`.
I am using a third party router to log-in inside a small robot I built. This robot will turn on using a relay which is triggered by a `combobox` and a related `button` which will apply the `combobox` choice. Also I am new to `JavaScript` and `HTML` and for this reason I learned how to deploy a website and I prepared a **minimal verifiable example** which can be found here https://comboboxtest.netlify.com/ and [here](https://github.com/emanueleraggi/combobox) you can also get the source code if needed.

The goal of the application after I launch `Visual Studio` will be:

1) log-in inside the router,

2) automatically trigger the combobox and

3) automatically apply the combobox choice using the `Apply` button.

For better showing this see print screen below:

[image: lay-out]

**The problem**: In order to access to the router there is an external interface that I didn't write because is from the router. I navigated through the interface and arrived to the `Apply` button as shown below in the `HTML` code:

[image: navigation]

So the operations are the following:

**1)** I trigger the relays using the combobox

**2)** using the mouse I have to hover on the `Apply` button

**3)** After the mouse is on the button (button hovered) I can click and apply the choice

**4)** The choice should be confirmed by the statement to become green.

**What is not working:** I can trigger the combobox, but I am not able to atomatically hover and click on the apply button.

Below the most important part of the code I am using:

```
property string get_relay_comboBox: "
      var comboBox = document.getElementsByName('859-2-2')[0];
      // find a target element.
      if (comboBox) {
        // Add event listener for combobox
        comboBox.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
          console.log('Change event detected:', e);
        });
        // Get new option index by flipping the current selected index
        var newIdx = (comboBox.selectedIndex + 1) % 2;
        // set the new index
        comboBox.selectedIndex = newIdx;
        // fire change event
        comboBox.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
      }
      else {
        console.error('comboBox not found!');
      }
    ";

property string applyBtn: "
    function fun('btnb btnhov') {
      document.getElementById('btn_Apply').click();
    }
";
```

**What I tried so far**

**1)** I research for a while the problem and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329978/change-selects-option-and-trigger-events-with-javascript) and also the [following post](http://jsfiddle.net/7fqr428m/) which helped to understand how to trigger the combobox.

**2)** I right clicked on the router interface right on the `Apply` button and opened the `Inspect Element` menu and went to the `Show DOM properties` I found that maybe the following sreen-shot could be useful:

[image: Show DOM properties]

**3)** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913171/how-to-trigger-the-html-select-onclick-event-activates-select-dropdown-with-opt) I used to understand the `HTML` part and in fact I understood that it is important the way components should be called but still could't figure out how to accept the choice of the combobox using the button.

**4)** Following this [source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp) which is the basic way to call a clicked event I simply applied it as it is possible to show it below:

```
    function fun('btnb btnhov') {
      document.getElementById('btn_Apply').click();
    }
```

But I didn't work and I think that at this point the most important problem as explained would be how to detect a mousover event and **after** that, push the button.
How to do that?

**EDITS**

I also tried to rewrite the function in the following way:

```
property string applyBtn: "
    var btnApply = document.getElementById('btn_Apply');
    if(btnApply) {
        // Try add event listener for button
        btnApply.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            console.log('Change event detected:', e);
        });
      // Push button
      // Here the button should be pushed (or hovered first????)
    }
    else {
        console.error('btnApply not found!');
    }
";
```

Thanks to anyone who could please guide to the right direction to solving this problem.

Comment: Does the function fun('btnb btnhov') get triggered at all?

Comment: @Trace, thanks for taking the time to read the question. I added **EDITS** on the question as I tried something else, but I don't see the function triggered, unless I am doing something wrong in the function I wrote

Comment: So what is the result of you edit? Was the button found and is the event listener added?

Comment: Nothing happened unfortunately

Comment: I don't know what this syntax `property string applyBtn` that you're using, but if it's automation you're looking for, I would look into Selenium webdriver: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium