# Right Click with Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am trying to test my GUI with Nightwatch. I can not seem to find how to simulate a right click. I went through the API Reference page(http://nightwatchjs.org/api) and searched everywhere. Am I missing something here? Because I believe that right clicking should be one of the most basic functionalities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good news !!!

Since Nightwatch.js **v0.6.13**, you can fire a **real right click** :-)

```
"Right Click to Show ContextMenu" : function (browser) {
  browser
   .moveToElement('#targetElement')
   .mouseButtonClick('right')
   .pause(5000)
   .end();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This **DOESN'T WORK**. I am going to leave it here anyways. It might be helpful somehow.

I found a work around. mousebuttonDown() method allows the use of left, middle and right clicks. They are assigned 0,1 and 2 respectively. So the following somehow simulates a rightclick:

```
"Right Click to Show ContextMenu" : function (browser) {
    browser
       .moveToElement(/*locate your element here*/)
       .mouseButtonDown(2)
       .mouseButtonUp(2)
       .end();
}
```

Comment: I opened a [pull request](https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/pull/425) on github project to fix this issue with the addition of a  new function : mouseButtonClick(2)

Comment: My pull request is accepted and merged ! I just posted a new answer. Test it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with selenium-webdriver ...

But right now i'm using that workaround for Nightwatch.js:

```
"Right Click to Show ContextMenu" : function (browser) {
     // inject script in client
     browser.execute(function(selector){
         // dispatch "context menu" event 
         $(selector).trigger('contextmenu');
         return true;
    }, ['#menu'])
    .pause(5000)
    .end();
}
```

(cf. [Nightwatch API](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#execute))

> Or in pure JS :
>   *document.querySelector('.logo').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('contextmenu'));*
>
> (cf.
>   [Trigger right click using pure Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914684/trigger-right-click-using-pure-javascript))

And check your target webpage :

```
   $('#menu').on('contextmenu', function () {
      alert('context menu');
      //return false;     // cancel default menu
   });
```