# Selenium right click in IE 11

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am automating a web application and facing few difficulties. Right click is not working in IE but is working in Chrome.

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id(conf.getPropertyValues("RIGHTCLICKTOMODIFY")));
    Actions action= new Actions(driver);
    action.contextClick(elem).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id(conf.getPropertyValues("RIGHTCLICK_MODIFY_LINK")));
```

Comment: Why are you using `SendKeys` in `ContextClick` method?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is an [open issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4403) that was not closed yet. You can try two possible work-arounds to solve this issue:

- Execute a script via `driver.executeScript(/* Do something */)` to simulate a [right-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914684/trigger-right-click-using-pure-javascript).
- Modify the capabilities of Internet Explorer by using `setCapability("nativeEvents",false)`, since it is possible that a browser does not support one or more `webdriver` feature. Have a look [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) for more insights on the subject.

I hope that my answer helps you.