# Javascript Dom Right Click Function

Tags: javascript, dom, simulate

This question was already asked in a simple way here: [Trigger right click using pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914684/trigger-right-click-using-pure-javascript), however, none of the answers there is what I (and apparently the poster of that thread) seek.

---

First and foremost, this question is not about events. I am not interested in knowing how to listen to a right click event (that would be a 'contextemenu' event). This is about simulating a right click on any DOM element, just by using the browsers console (chrome, in my case), and therefore JavaScript/DOM manipulation.

---

That been said, I know that there is a simple function to do the same thing, except it triggers a left ("normal") click, on any element. 
For instance, the famous...

[image: I'm not a robot captcha]

I found out that if you look at the source code, and somehow get a reference to the checkbox element, or the "div" where it is contained, lets say you get the ID, so you create a variable like this...

```
myElement = document.getElementById('Id_here');
```

you can simulate a click just by typing this into the browsers console:

```
myElement.click();
```

And the result will be:

[image: captcha solved!]

So, we simulated a real click, solving the captcha, no mouse needed, and more important, no human needed (if you implement this on a script)

---

The question now is pretty simple...

### Is there anything like i this but with the right click?

Something like *myElement.rightClick();* or *myElement.contextClick();*?

---

DISCLAIMER

This is just for research and knowledge purposes only.
Yes, I have searched in many sites, but they always talk about the event, nothing like what I'm asking for.
I would appreciate it a lot if anyone could answer this question, even if the answer is *"No, you can't "*. However, if you are going to state that, please be 100% sure that it is not possible or plausible. **As always, thanks in advance!**

Comment: if jQuery is an option you could refer to the answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2725963/2675902).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yap easy:

```
var element = document.getElementById('Id_here');
if (window.CustomEvent) {
    element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('contextmenu'));
} else if (document.createEvent) {
    var ev = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    ev.initEvent('contextmenu', true, false);
    element.dispatchEvent(ev);
} else { // Internet Explorer
    element.fireEvent('oncontextmenu');
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work for me.