# Re-using same instance again webdriverJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am really new to Selenium. I managed to open a website using the below nodejs code

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();
console.log(driver);

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com');

 //perform all other operations here.
```

https://web.whatsapp.com is opened and I manually scan a QR code and log in. Now I have different javascript files to perform actions like delete, clear chat inside web.whatsapp.com etc...

Now If I get some error, I debug and when I run the script again using `node test.js`, it takes another 2 minutes to load page and do the steps I needed. I just wanted to reopen the already opened tab and continue my script instead new window opens.

Edit day 2 : Still searching for solution. I tried below code to save object and reuse it.. Is this the correct approach ? I get a JSON parse error though.

```
var o = new chrome.Options();
o.addArguments("user-data-dir=/Users/vishnu/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 2");
o.addArguments("disable-infobars");
o.addArguments("--no-first-run");

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).setChromeOptions(o).build();
    var savefile = fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(util.inspect(driver)) , 'utf-8');
    var parsedJSON = require('./data.json');
    console.log(parsedJSON);
```

Comment: You need to include all of your tests within one script (or require them).

Comment: I can include , but if i rerun the program its opening completely new window

Comment: I am looking into this, but it's complex... Also a very interesting question though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time and a couple of different approaches, but I managed to work up something I think solves your problem and allows to develop tests in a rather nice way.

Because it does not directly answer the question of how to re-use a browser session in [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) (using their [JavaScript API](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/)), I will first present my proposed solution and then briefly discuss the other approaches I tried. It may give someone else an idea and help them to solve this problem in a nicer/better way. Who knows. At least my attempts will be documented.

## Proposed solution (tested and works)

Because I did not manage to actually reuse a browser session (see below), I figured I could try something else. The approach will be the following.

### Idea

1. Have a main loop in one file (say `init.js`) and tests in a separate file (`test.js`).
2. The main loop opens a browser instance and keeps it open. It also exposes some sort of CLI that allows one to run tests (from `test.js`), inspect errors as they occur and to close the browser instance and stop the main loop.
3. The test in `test.js` exports a test function that is being executed by the main loop. It is passed a driver instance to work with. Any errors that occur here are being caught by the main loop.

Because the browser instance is opened only once, we have to do the manual process of authenticating with WhatsApp (scanning a QR code) only once. After that, running a test will reload [web.whatsapp.com](https://web.whatsapp.com/), but it will have remembered that we authenticated and thus immediately be able to run whatever tests we define in `test.js`.

In order to keep the main loop alive, it is vital that we catch each and every error that might occur in our tests. I unfortunately had to resort to [`uncaughtException`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) for that.

### Implementation

This is the implementation of the above idea I came up with. It is possible to make this much fancier if you would want to do so. I went for simplicity here (hope I managed).

**init.js**
This is the main loop from the above idea.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    by = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until,
    driver = null,
    prompt = '> ',
    testPath = 'test.js',
    lastError = null;

function initDriver() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // already opened a browser? done
        if (driver !== null) {
            resolve();
            return;
        }
        // open a new browser, let user scan QR code
        driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
        driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com');
        process.stdout.write("Please scan the QR code within 30 seconds...\n");
        driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.className('chat')), 30000)
            .then(() => resolve())
            .catch((timeout) => {
                process.stdout.write("\b\bTimed out waiting for code to" +
                    " be scanned.\n");
                driver.quit();
                reject();
            });
    });
}

function recordError(err) {
    process.stderr.write(err.name + ': ' + err.message + "\n");
    lastError = err;
    // let user know that test failed
    process.stdout.write("Test failed!\n");
    // indicate we are ready to read the next command
    process.stdout.write(prompt);
}

process.stdout.write(prompt);
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
    var chunk = process.stdin.read();
    if (chunk === null) {
        // happens on initialization, ignore
        return;
    }
    // do various different things for different commands
    var line = chunk.trim(),
        cmds = line.split(/\s+/);
    switch (cmds[0]) {
        case 'error':
            // print last error, when applicable
            if (lastError !== null) {
                console.log(lastError);
            }
            // indicate we are ready to read the next command
            process.stdout.write(prompt);
            break;
        case 'run':
            // open a browser if we didn't yet, execute tests
            initDriver().then(() => {
                // carefully load test code, report SyntaxError when applicable
                var file = (cmds.length === 1 ? testPath : cmds[1] + '.js');
                try {
                    var test = require('./' + file);
                } catch (err) {
                    recordError(err);
                    return;
                } finally {
                    // force node to read the test code again when we
                    // require it in the future
                    delete require.cache[__dirname + '/' + file];
                }
                // carefully execute tests, report errors when applicable
                test.execute(driver, by, until)
                    .then(() => {
                        // indicate we are ready to read the next command
                        process.stdout.write(prompt);
                    })
                    .catch(recordError);
            }).catch(() => process.stdin.destroy());
            break;
        case 'quit':
            // close browser if it was opened and stop this process
            if (driver !== null) {
                driver.quit();
            }
            process.stdin.destroy();
            return;
    }
});

// some errors somehow still escape all catches we have...
process.on('uncaughtException', recordError);
```

**test.js**
This is the test from the above idea. I wrote some things just to test the main loop and some WebDriver functionality. Pretty much anything is possible here. I have used [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to make test execution work nicely with the main loop.

```
var driver, by, until,
    timeout = 5000;

function waitAndClickElement(selector, index = 0) {
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.css(selector)), timeout)
        .then(() => {
            driver.findElements(by.css(selector)).then((els) => {
                var element = els[index];
                driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(element), timeout);
                element.click();
            });
        });
}

exports.execute = function(d, b, u) {
    // make globally accessible for ease of use
    driver = d;
    by = b;
    until = u;
    // actual test as a promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // open site
        driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com');
        // make sure it loads fine
        driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.className('chat')), timeout);
        driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(
            driver.findElement(by.className('chat'))), timeout);
        // open menu
        waitAndClickElement('.icon.icon-menu');
        // click profile link
        waitAndClickElement('.menu-shortcut', 1);
        // give profile time to animate
        // this prevents an error from occurring when we try to click the close
        // button while it is still being animated (workaround/hack!)
        driver.sleep(500);
        // close profile
        waitAndClickElement('.btn-close-drawer');
        driver.sleep(500); // same for hiding profile
        // click some chat
        waitAndClickElement('.chat', 3);
        // let main script know we are done successfully
        // we do so after all other webdriver promise have resolved by creating
        // another webdriver promise and hooking into its resolve
        driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.className('chat')), timeout)
            .then(() => resolve());
    });
};
```

### Example output

Here is some example output. The first invocation of `run test` will open up an instance of Chrome. Other invocations will use that same instance. When an error occurs, it can be inspected as shown. Executing `quit` will close the browser instance and quit the main loop.

```
$ node init.js
> run test
> run test
WebDriverError: unknown error: Element <div class="chat">...</div> is not clickable at point (163, 432). Other element would receive the click: <div dir="auto" contenteditable="false" class="input input-text">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.9.0-2-amd64 x86_64)
Test failed!
> error
<prints complete stacktrace>
> run test
> quit
```

You can run tests in other files by simply calling them. Say you have a file `test-foo.js`, then execute `run test-foo` in the above prompt to run it. All tests will share the same Chrome instance.

---

## Failed attempt #1: saving and restoring storage

When inspecting the page using my development tools, I noticed that it appears to use the [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). It is possible to [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) this as JSON  and [write](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) it to a file. On a next invocation, this file can be [read](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options), [parsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and written to the new browser instance storage before reloading the page.

Unfortunately, WhatsApp still required me to scan the QR code. I have tried to figure out what I missed (cookies, `sessionStorage`, ...), but did not manage. It is possible that WhatsApp registers the browser as being disconnected after some time has passed. Or that it uses other browser properties (session ID?) to recognize the browser. This is pure speculating from my side though.

---

## Failed attempt #2: switching session/window

Every browser instance started via WebDriver has a session ID. This ID can be retrieved, so I figured it may be possible to start a session and then connect to it from the test cases, which would then be run from a separate file (you can see this is the predecessor of the final solution). Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure out a way to set the session ID. This may actually be a security concern, I am not sure. People more expert in the usage of WebDriver might be able to clarify here.

I did find out that it is possible to [retrieve a list of window handles](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebDriver.html#getAllWindowHandles) and switch between [them](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_TargetLocator.html#window). Unfortunately, windows are only shared within a single session and not across sessions.

Comment: Actually , I can use reuse the session , I dont have to manually scan the QR code everytime ,, I just use profile ,, please see my question I edited code I used..I created a profile in chrome and I used that profile path in var o = new chrome.Options(); .. so when I reopen browser ,, it use same session... but my problem is when i run test and run into error , I need to edit code and re run it ,, let me read your answer and get back to you...and btw thanks a ton bro.

Comment: I guess with chrome options  , you could have saved more time ! cos it always saves session when browser is reopened,,,

Comment: And yea I retreived session ID , but there was no documentation to set it ,, but I read in 2 or 3 sites where they set .. but they doing it only with remote connections.

Comment: Right, I misunderstood your question then. So, you want to continue your tests at a specific point? Say, you did steps 1 through 142 and now you want to continue at 143, where it previously crashed?

Comment: yes exactly , but without reopening new window... just like we do in imacros .. or developer console in certain webpages..

Comment: Let me ask for some more clarification [in chat](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141945/re-using-same-instance-again-webdriverjs).

Comment: Hi , works awesome , thanks alot :) can I get your skype ID ,, if any doubt I will ask you

Comment: Cheers! Glad to hear that. I don't use Skype, but you can use the chatroom here and ping me using a comment if something comes up.

Comment: can you tell how to do it with mocha js ?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to modify `init.js` to not have `var test = require('./' + testPath);`, but instead [run Mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically). Of course, `test.js` would then have to be changed to be a Mocha-compatible test.

Comment: hi , I have one down ,, Now I am doing some test in for loop ,, with waitandclickelement function... now if the element is not found script is stopping... I just want to continue the script even if element not found to next step.. how to do it ?

Comment: Nice! The `waitAndClickElement` function explicitly waits until an element is visible (fails if it is not) and then clicks it. You can create a separate function that clicks an element if it exists and does nothing otherwise - is that what you want? For that, don't do the wait, but immediately execute [`findElements`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Driver.html#findElements) and check for a non-zero length to see if the element exists.

Comment: If I do that ,, its running asynchronously.. and stops working for 2nd loop

Comment: I don't quite see why that'd happen. Can you provide an example of that?

Comment: I fixed it thanks ,, Please check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609259/webdriverjs-set-viewport-size , been struggling on that for 8 hours lol

Comment: hi , Just want to say you thanks , your code works amazing , I have another doubt..I am running test by node init.js and then typing js ,, now if i have multiple test files like test1.js , test2.js ,, how to run it on the fly ,, without changing file name in init.js

Comment: @Vishnu I updated `init.js` to support different commands. You can now do `run` (which runs the file defined in `testPath`), or `run test2` to run `test2.js`, et cetera. Hope that helps!

Comment: How to check if either class1 or class2 exists.. like driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.class(class1)) OR driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.class(class2))  ,, if either of one satisfies,,, finish the waiting and go to next

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question for that one, I'll be able to look into that in a couple of hours.

Comment: Ok I am making one ,,  btw your newly update init.js not working for me !

Comment: Meh, maybe I rushed too much. It was working for me though. Are you using run instead of test now? I can also take a look at that...

Comment: I used run test and its working ,, now  I am facing few problems ,,when I open browser , cache is not being reused ,, and when I do run test after test failed , its crashing ,,, also please tell command to stop test1 forcefully and run test2

Comment: hey bro you here ? I have a prbolem, when I run test.js , if there is timeout error , full script is stopping , I have to run node init again..