# WebdriverJS Set viewport Size

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I want to launch chrome browser with viewport size of some resolution , for example 800x600 , I tried following code

```
var width = 800;
var height = 600;
driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
```

Above code just resizing window to 800x600 , when I run `window.screen.width` in developer console it always return  `1440`

I even tried to add chrome option with `--window-size=x,y` option

```
var o = new chrome.Options();
o.addArguments("--window-size=640,480");

driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).setChromeOptions(o).build();
```

Above code still do the same ,just resizing the window.

Some one please tell me any chrome command line option to set default viewport like we do in chrome developer console (as shown below) , or please tell any option to do directly in selenium webdriverJS.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**
It seems that you really want to influence what `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height` return. This is normally not possible, except that these values change when using the [device mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/) (and [toolbar](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports)) in Chrome. So, let's trigger those, right?

```
// open inspector and responsive design mode
driver.actions()
    .keyDown(Key.CONTROL)
    .keyDown(Key.SHIFT)
    .sendKeys('im')
    .keyUp(Key.SHIFT)
    .keyUp(Key.CONTROL)
    .perform();
```

Unfortunately, this [**won't work** in Chrome](//stackoverflow.com/a/36311297/962603). To quote that answer:

> The Chrome driver uses the Chrome remote debugging protocol to communicate with the browser. This is the same protocol that the developer console uses also. Unfortunately, Chrome is designed so that only one client can be attached using the protocol at a time, so that means either the developer tools, or the driver, but not both simultaneously.    — [JimEvans](//stackoverflow.com/users/374693/jimevans)

Bummer. It looks like this can be made to work [using Firefox](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1175), however. Unfortunately, it seems that performing actions is [currently not possible](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/233) using Selenium + geckodriver, at the moment. It is also not possible to open this mode using JavaScript. We can however send keys to an element.

**A solution**
The following works for me.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    Key = webdriver.Key,
    driver = null;

// construct driver
var profile = new firefox.Profile(),
    devicePreset = [{
        width: 640,
        height: 480,
        key: '640x480',
        name: 'Mobile Device'
    }];
profile.setPreference('devtools.responsiveUI.presets',
                      JSON.stringify(devicePreset));
var opts = new firefox.Options();
opts.setProfile(profile);
var builder = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox');
builder.setFirefoxOptions(opts);
driver = builder.build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');

// open responsive design mode
driver.findElement(By.css('input[name="q"]'))
    .sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, Key.SHIFT, 'm'));

driver.get('https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address');
```

Note that I set a preference for Firefox that indicates the size to use in the responsive design mode. You can change this to whatever screen size you prefer.

Comment: Brilliant , will try this and let you know :) accepting and giving bounty now

Answer (score 2):

The code you are providing is working perfectly fine.

However, you are checking the resolution of the [screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen), not the size of the [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)! This is what [`window.screen.width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width) and `window.screen.height` refer to. To retrieve the size of the window, use [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) (and `innerHeight`). The following works for me.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    driver = null;

function logWindowSize() {
    driver.executeScript(function() {
        return [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
    }).then(console.log);
}

// construct driver
driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
    .build();
driver.get('http://www.google.com');

// resize window
logWindowSize();
driver.manage().window().setSize(640, 480);
logWindowSize();
driver.quit();
```

This will log the following to my console.

```
[ 945, 1018 ]
[ 640, 375 ]
```

Note that the height of the window is different from what was set. This is because of the height of the tab bar and navigation bar. You can set the inner window size by first setting it to an arbitrary value, checking the difference and then setting it to what you want plus that difference. like so.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    driver = null,
    sizeWidth = 640,
    sizeHeight = 480;

// construct driver
driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
    .build();
driver.get('http://www.google.com');

// resize window
driver.manage().window().setSize(sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
driver.executeScript(function() {
    return [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
}).then(function(actualSize) {
    driver.manage().window().setSize(
        2 * sizeWidth - actualSize[0],
        2 * sizeHeight - actualSize[1]
    );
    // the following will log the sizes we want
    driver.executeScript(function() {
        return [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
    }).then(console.log);
});
driver.quit();
```

Comment: I mean , when I visit the site https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address  , whatever I do it shows my screen resolution ,, but if i click inspect element and click Mobile Icon like the screenshot in my question , and if I reload the site ,, size is changed in  https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address  ..I want like that via selenium... your code too doesnt work

Comment: hey bro , can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645185/click-only-visible-element-selenium-webdriverjs