# click only visible element selenium webdriverjs

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have multiple div like below

```
<div class="one">send Message</div>

<div class="one">send Message</div>

<div class="one">send Message</div>
```

I have a web page where there is send Message buttons like above, in which only one button is visible at a time.Other two buttons are hidden via some javascript codes.So for example if 2nd button is visible , I should be able to click only that element.But in my selenium code , its trying to click first hidden div and its failing

```
 driver.findElements(by.className(".one")).then((els) => {
            var element = els[index];
            element.click();
        });
```

So basically I wanna convert below javascript code to Selenium nodejs code,If some one guide me that will be helpful

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
    if (isHidden(all[i]))
        // hidden
    else 
        // visible
}

function isHidden(el) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    return ((style.display === 'none') || (style.visibility === 'hidden'))
}
```

Comment: Did you try `try`/`catch`?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to click the button ( basically a div as far as code is concerned ) which is visible ?

If that is your main agenda, then the code you've written will fail to find desired element. As you are selecting the element by it's classname not its visibility.

Your code will find all the matched class element. As it's a basic element selector and all your buttons have the same class, so they are basically rendered on the page.

### Approach 1

```
driver.findElements(by.className(".one")).then((els) => {
        for(var key in els){
             var element = els[key];
             if(element.isDisplayed()){ //if visible element
               element.click();            
             }
        }
    });
```

The Key here is to check if the element you are trying to click is visible on the page.

### Approach 2

By giving a unique class to the target button. Some class for eg 'clickable' or 'active'. So it will be a more optimized solution to select the target element using the Css selector. The Key here is to give uniqueness to your target element to be more identifiable.

Comment: Oops, I copied your code as it is. Actually you are getting set of elements. So you need to iterate them. Updated my code just check now.

Answer (score 0):

Usually many Java Scripts are run in the node Js without the convert.
Have you try it in the node Js without converting ???
** Remember to import selenium