# How to simulate right button click on JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the code below to simulate a mouse click on a DOM element. It works, but how can i adjust this code to simulate a RIGHT button click instead ?

```
var selNode = document.getElementById('myelement');
var nodeClientRect = selNode.getBoundingClientRect();selNode.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mousedown", {bubbles: true,cancelable: true,screenX: nodeClientRect.x,screenY: nodeClientRect.y}));
```

Comment: Did you try to fire 'contextmenu' event?

Comment: `contextmenu` event or maybe an if inside mousedown `if (ev.which == 3)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger right click using pure Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914684/trigger-right-click-using-pure-javascript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914684/trigger-right-click-using-pure-javascript